# How to map two entities with id of third entity?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

I have following tables:

```
user:         id, name, credit_card_id
credit_card:  id, value
balance:      id, value, credit_card_id
```

How should looks like Doctrine mapping to get from `User` entity all `Balance` entities related to the user's `CreditCard` ?

I have tried with `OneToMany` relation but with no luck:

```
class User {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var CreditCard
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="CreditCard", inversedBy="user")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="credit_card_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $creditCard;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Balance", mappedBy="user")
     */
    protected $balances;

}

class Balance {

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="float")
     */
    protected $value;


    /**
     * @var CreditCard
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CreditCard")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="credit_card_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $creditCard;

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="balances")
     */
    protected $user;

}

class CreditCard
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="value", type="string")
     */
    protected $value;

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="creditCard")
     */
    protected $user;

}
```

Comment: You mean you would like to have something like

    user -> card -> balance

right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a credit_card is realated to a user, you should consider to make an association between user and credit_card and between credit_card and balance. 
In that way, you could retrieve what you need. Otherwise, if you haven't association between Balance and Credit_Card (even if I see it into your table representation) isn't possibile to retrieve this "directly" (so through class members). In the latter case, you have to write a custom DQL query.

**update**

Your entity and db design are tricky for ORM. A possible solution (but is inefficient from my point of view) is the following

o) Fetch **all** user balances: `$balances = $user->getBalances();`
o) Fetch user credit card: `$cc = $user->getCreditCard();`
o) Remove all balances that aren't "linked" with credit card you've fetched

```
   creditCardBalance = new ArrayCollection();
   foreach($balances as $balance)
   {
     if($balance->getCreditCard()->getId() )= $cc->getId())
     {
       creditCardBalance->add($balance)
     }
   }
```

An alternative way (more efficent) is to change your mappings in the following way

```
class Balance {

    /**
     * @var CreditCard
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CreditCard", inversedBy="balances")
     */
    protected $creditCard;

}

class CreditCard
{

    /**
     * @var Balances
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Balance", mappedBy="creditCard")
     */
    protected $balances;

}
```

In that way you could retrieve directly what you need, in the following way

```
$cc = $user->getCreditCard();
$balances = $cc->getBalances();
```

**Please, pay attention:** don't forget to make doctrine generate entities for your (if you want setter and getter "free") and don't forget to update database schema

Comment: There are already relations between `User` - `CreditCard` and `Balance` - `CreditCard`. Isn't it possible to fetch `Balance` entities without custom DQL ?

Comment: @hsz: post your whole relations please, then I can be more helpful :)